# подключение OpenGL к GLFW на c#

Tags: c#, opengl, glfw

хотел использовать `OpenGL` и `GLFW`. 
подключил https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net
и https://github.com/Chman/Glfw.Net
но на экран не чего не выводится.
вот код

```
using Glfw3;
using OpenGL;
using System;

class Example
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{


    if (!Glfw.Init())
        Environment.Exit(-1);

    var window = Glfw.CreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World");
    if (!window)
    {
        Glfw.Terminate();
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }

    Glfw.MakeContextCurrent(window);


    while (!Glfw.WindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
        Gl.ClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Glfw.SwapBuffers(window);

        Glfw.PollEvents();
    }

    Glfw.Terminate();
}
}
```

Comment: Отладчиком проходили, все строки отрабатывают?

Comment: "но на экран не чего не выводится. вот код" это что значит? Нет окна или окно чёрное?

Comment: @Unick окно чёрное

Comment: Вообще правильно сначала устанавливать цвет Gl.ClearColor, а потом чистить Gl.Clear.

Comment: @Unick нечего не изменилось.

Comment: Возможно вы не настроили  viewport: Gl.Viewport(0, 0, window_w, window_h);

Answer (score 0):

Вызовите функцию `Gl.Initialize()` для инициализации OpenGL, **перед** созданием контекста.